# Getting error in update function code in Dao Class

Tags: java, wildfly, jpql, dao

I am trying to update values stored in my database table.
But i am getting error "No row with the given identifier exists: [this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database#3]"

piece of code that i am trying to run

```
public Integer findPersonXHrUserId(String nic)
    {
      Query query = em.createQuery("select u.userId from XHrUser u where (u.nic) = (:nic)")
              .setParameter("nic", nic);
      List<Integer> list = query.getResultList();
      return list.isEmpty() || list.get(0) == null ? 0 : list.get(0);
    }


public void UpdateUserInDbTable(String firstName, String lastName, String nic, String phoneNumber, String emailAddress) {

        int userId = findPersonXHrUserId(nic);

        XHrUser xHrUserObj= new XHrUser();

        xHrUserObj.setUserId(userId);
        xHrUserObj.setFirstName(firstName);
        xHrUserObj.setLastName(lastName);
        xHrUserObj.setNic(nic);
        xHrUserObj.setPhone(phoneNumber);
        xHrUserObj.setEmail(emailAddress);

        em.persist(xHrUserObj);

        xHrUserObj= em.find(XHrUser.class, xHrUserObj.getUserId());     
        em.merge(xHrUserObj);
        em.refresh(xHrUserObj);


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: so ... you try to update non-existing data. how do you expect this to work?

Comment: there is data already present in database, i m trying to update some columns with the new data

Comment: maybe you get 0 from `findPersonXHrUserId` and the `em.persist`'s trying to update with the `userId = 0`

Comment: no, when i tried to debug it, values that i got for userId were correct.   Data that i m trying to modify was in row 3 and userId value was also 3

Comment: just because there is data present, doesn't mean the data you try to update is there

Comment: row #3 and userId 3 are not the same. it's also not what your query compares

Comment: By row3 i meant userId 3

Comment: The persist will not store it in the database until the transaction ends

Answer (score 0):

i removed persist and it worked..

Comment: Your usage of em.merge is wrong... The **return value** of that call is the merged entiy!!! So you are effectively tried to commit the non-merged item...